# Can i be sued when im just getting back on my feet

Tags: covid-19, arbitration, civil, collections, garnishment

im being sued for becoming default on truck payments because during covid i became homeless ended up living in my truck with 3 children n then was gifted a camper we lived in camper for a year with no help from noone because we werent considered first priority because of so many homeless ..im just getting back on my own feet got a home finally started working and just got my license back got the truck fixed and im being sued which will make me loose everything I just accomplished...I live 20 miles from my job I live way out in the words there's no public transportation if I loose my truck I loose my job therefore my house I'll be back on the street again help me find a way to avoid this

is there anyway of winning the lawsuit against me or settling with a payment plan

Answer (score 2):

Fact is: Whoever wants to sue you will get very little or no money out of you, even if they win. If you manage to convince them to accept a payment plan, they will get a lot more. Unless there is some personal reason why bankrupting you is more important than gettin money out of you, they should accept this.

On the other hand, you should check out with a lawyer what happens if you declare yourself bankrupt. There’s a good chance that your home (as your place of living) and your car (as your only means to get to work and make money) would be protected. In other words, whoever you owe money would get exactly nothing. But for that you need to talk to some professional.